# Creating a view matrix with glm

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to create a view matrix with glm. I know of `glm::lookAt` and understand how it works. I want to know if there are similar functions that will acheive the same outcome that take different parameters. For example, is there a function that takes an up-vector, a directional bearing on the plane perpendicular(?) to the vector, and an angle? (i.e. The sky is that way, I turn N degrees/radians to my left and tilt my head M degrees/radians upward).

Comment: Knowing these it should be trivial to convert them into set of parameters LookAt needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just build the matrix by composing a set of operations:

```
// define your up vector
glm::vec3 upVector = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
// rotate around to a given bearing: yaw
glm::mat4 camera = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), bearing, upVector);
// Define the 'look up' axis, should be orthogonal to the up axis
glm::vec3 pitchVector = glm::vec3(1, 0, 0);
// rotate around to the required head tilt: pitch
camera = glm::rotate(camera, tilt, pitchVector);

// now get the view matrix by taking the camera inverse
glm::mat4 view = glm::inverse(camera);
```

Comment: Thank you, that should help solve my immediate problem. However, I am still curious to know if there are any other 'convenience' functions in glm for creating matrices.